# Google Cloud Custom VM Instance with Custom Script to Customize the Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking for ideas on how to customize the Google Cloud VM instance.

One of my very simple needs is to execute a script soon after startup.

How to go about?

Thanks

Naga Vijayapuram

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it ...

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance \
  --metadata-from-file startup-script=scripts/abc.sh \
  --subnet=default \
  --zone=us-central1-b
```